# Android wifi hotspot shows up no matter where I am

Tags: wi-fi

I'm having some odd behavior on my Galaxy S3. Suddenly, there's another Wi-Fi hotspot showing up, which shouldn't be weird, except it shows up literally everywhere I go.

I work in Austin, but live an hour east of the city. The same Wi-Fi SSID is showing up not only at both locations, but on the entirety of the drive between the two. It's not a network I've ever seen or connected to before, and it doesn't give me the option to forget the network.

It's not showing a signal strong enough to connect (0 bars), but it's always showing up as:

```
sabasissy - Secured (WPS available)
```

I can see my home network just fine, and my neighbors. I can walk out into the hills behind my house, that were destroyed by a wildfire 3 years ago, with literally nothing around me for a half-mile radius, and still, this network shows up.

I don't think it's a legit hotspot, as my laptop shows only my and my neighbor's Wi-Fi, with even stronger signals than the phone, but doesn't see this new hotspot at all.

Probably also not a Bells of St. John scenario, either. Could this be an indication of some sort of infection/rootkit on my phone? Where does Android store the list of available connections between scans, and is it possible that something's just written to that file and is keeping it from being deleted?

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**: Ran WiFi Analyzer all the way from home to work this morning, watching as it picked up access points along the way. The one in question never wavered, always showing up -90 dBm. Played with some of the options when I got to work, and noticed that the AP's MAC address is all zeroes.

[image: All Zero MAC Address]

**Update 2**: Restarted my phone, and it appears to have gone away for now.

Comment: It's showing up because you remembered it, this behavior, is normal

Comment: @Ramhound: I've never seen, nor connected to this network until it popped up recently. If I had, I'd be able to hold my finger on it until it gives me the option to "Forget Network", which as I mentioned, it does not. A long press just gives me "Connect to network".

Comment: There are no known infections for android, most reports of malicious activity, are rogue programs user download

Comment: Interesting. Only new apps I've installed in months are Google Authenticator and Microsoft Account after someone tried to break into my XBL account. Might be time to wipe and reinstall.